# Setting up build environment using source file inside bash script does not work

Tags: python, bash, shell

So I have a build environment that gets setup when I do a `. setup` or `source setup`.
There are a bunch of commands (lets say `command abc`, `command xyz`) that become available once the setup file is sourced which I need to use inside a bash script. So I have to do something like this :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd build_dir

. setup

command abc && command xyz
```

And then on calling my script, I expect `command abc` and `command xyz` to have been executed.
But instead I see an error saying `command abc not Found`.

The setup environment is complex enough that I wouldn't want to bog my script with adding all the commands and env variables manually, I'd rather ditch the script completely.

Why is this happening and is there anyway of doing this with either shell scripting or python?

Comment: try `source setup`

Comment: unless the `command` identifier was just a toy example, maybe your question/issue comes from the fact `command` is precisely a builtin command? try e.g. `type command` or `man command`

Comment: Please make this reproducible. As it is right now, we can only guess. From the little information in this question, I cannot find any reason why this shouldn't work (assuming `command abc` is just a placeholder for another command, as ErikMD pointed out).

Comment: source setup also doesn't work

Comment: command abc is an alias. It will be building multiple dependencies and cleaning old bin files.

Answer (score 0):

`command abc` means to ignore any alias or function named *abc*  and instead searches an executable file inside the directories listed in $PATH. Obviously there is no such file on your system.

So, you need to know where your file `abc` is located. Then you have two possibilities: Either add this directory to your PATH,

```
PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar/abcdir
```

or you don't use `command`, but execute your program using the explicit path, i.e.

```
/foo/bar/abcdir/abc && command xyz
```